# RStudio fails to open on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

When I want to open RStudio (RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea " (547dcf86, 2023-07-06) for macOS) on MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 I get the following error message:

**Error Starting R**

The R session failed to start.

**RSTUDIO VERSION**
RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea " (547dcf86, 2023-07-06) for macOS

[No error available]

[No errors emitted]

**OUTPUT**

[No output emitted]

```
/Users/username/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-username.log
2023-07-12T14:21:27.894940Z [rsession-username] ERROR offlineConnectionMatcher: ignoring connection received in the future; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::offlineConnectionMatcher(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point) src/cpp/session/SessionOfflineService.cpp:131
2023-07-12T14:21:27.895053Z [rsession-username] ERROR offlineConnectionMatcher: ignoring connection received in the future; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::offlineConnectionMatcher(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point) src/cpp/session/SessionOfflineService.cpp:131
2023-07-12T14:21:27.895156Z [rsession-username] ERROR offlineConnectionMatcher: ignoring connection received in the future; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::offlineConnectionMatcher(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point) src/cpp/session/SessionOfflineService.cpp:131
```

Comment: This may be a better fit for the RStudio community support page https://community.rstudio.com/ or their github issues page https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this folder and delete it: ~/.local/share/rstudio

You can follow the instructions here:

https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: Works perfectly well!! Thank you so much you are saving my live how could I ever thank you <3

Comment: Why are you so good and know that? You seem to be a genius? Ever thought of getting a nobel prize?