# Fatal error encountered when starting RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

I've installed R:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
```

and I've installed RStudio:

```
2023.06.2+561 "Mountain Hyranga " (de44a311, 2023-0825) for macOS
```

but permanently get this error when starting RStudio:

```
R session failed to start.
```

Who can help?

**Full trouble report**:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.06.2+561 "Mountain Hydrangea " (de44a311, 2023-08-25) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.06.2+561 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*/Users/chris/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-chris.log*

```
2023-09-20T13:14:10.545179Z [rsession-chris] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-chris): ;|||rstudio-0.js#-1::new _re|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.java#138::checkIndexBoundsForAccess|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.java#285::showWidget|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.java#661::selectTab|||org/rstudio/core/client/theme/DocTabLayoutPanel.java#325::selectTab|||org/rstudio/core/client/theme/DocTabLayoutPanel.java#345::selectTab|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.java#711::selectTab|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourcePane.java#155::selectTab|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourceColumn.java#537::lambda$6|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourceColumn.java#537::onEnsureVisible|||org/rstudio/core/client/events/EnsureVisibleEvent.java#46::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTarget.java#400::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/model/DocUpdateSentinel.java#413::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/model/DocUpdateSentinel.java#550::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/server/remote/RemoteServer.java#3418::onResponseReceived|||org/rstudio/studio/client/server/remote/RemoteServer.java#3491::onError|||org/rstudio/core/client/jsonrpc/RpcRequest.java#133::onResponseReceived|||com/google/gwt/http/client/Request.java#233::fireOnResponseReceived|||com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.java#409::onReadyStateChange|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh  Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36
2023-09-20T13:14:10.545179Z [rsession-chris] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-chris): ;|||rstudio-0.js#-1::new _re|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.java#138::checkIndexBoundsForAccess|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.java#285::showWidget|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.java#661::selectTab|||org/rstudio/core/client/theme/DocTabLayoutPanel.java#325::selectTab|||org/rstudio/core/client/theme/DocTabLayoutPanel.java#345::selectTab|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.java#711::selectTab|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourcePane.java#155::selectTab|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourceColumn.java#537::lambda$6|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/SourceColumn.java#537::onEnsureVisible|||org/rstudio/core/client/events/EnsureVisibleEvent.java#46::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTarget.java#400::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/model/DocUpdateSentinel.java#413::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/model/DocUpdateSentinel.java#550::onError|||org/rstudio/studio/client/server/remote/RemoteServer.java#3418::onResponseReceived|||org/rstudio/studio/client/server/remote/RemoteServer.java#3491::onError|||org/rstudio/core/client/jsonrpc/RpcRequest.java#133::onResponseReceived|||com/google/gwt/http/client/Request.java#233::fireOnResponseReceived|||com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.java#409::onReadyStateChange|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh  Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673179/rstudio-fails-to-open-on-mac

Comment: yes I did but couldn' make sense of it