I am getting an error trying to start RStudio
RStudio does not open on my Mac and it keeps crashing. I've tried uninstalling R and RStudio and install different versions of RStudio. I have also updated my Mac and tried re-installing. When it starts, I get a message that says "R has encountered a fatal error".
I am running on macOS Sonoma 14.5.
If I open R outside of RStudio it works. A very interesting issue is that when I create a new user on my mac and try to open RStudio there, it works. I have attached an image of what it looks like when I try to open RStudio. Below is the error message that I copied.
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2024.04.1+748 "Chocolate Cosmos " (3ada7c6d, 2024-05-06) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2024.04.1+748 Chrome/120.0.6099.291 Electron/28.2.6 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1. 

Error output:


[No errors emitted]

Standard output:


[No output emitted]

### Logs

*/Users/anjanamohan/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-anjanamohan.log*



) [errormsg: Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: 0x0>,  :
NULL value passed as symbol address
]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::(anonymous namespace)::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP *, sexp::Protect *, rstudio::r::exec::(anonymous namespace)::EvalType) src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:231; LOGGED FROM: json::Value rstudio::session::modules::environment::varToJson(SEXP, const r::sexp::Variable &) src/cpp/session/modules/environment/EnvironmentUtils.cpp:223


Try by running sudo chown $USER ~/.local/share in your terminal.

Can I just copy-paste what you have written there? Or should I replace "USER"?

I tried this, and it does not work

The code was meant to be run as shown. What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76673562/5221626
